# Azure rest api endpoint to read the Azure functions appsettings

Tags: azure-functions

I'm looking for an Azure REST API to list the Azure Functions appsettings defined in the Azure portal. Based on the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings), it looks like supporting three options

- Using Azure portal
- Using Azure CLI
- Using Powershell utility

Is there any REST API endpoint that I can use to get the list of appsettings for Azure function app?

Comment: May I know if the api provided below meet your requirement ? If it helps your problem, could you please mark the answer as "accepted", thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listapplicationsettings):

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/config/appsettings/list?api-version=2019-08-01
```